# Save button after entering new passwords

Tags: php, forms, cakephp

I have posted the demo here http://jsfiddle.net/Z9JmB/5/

I would like to display the view (cakephp) but after clicking the save button to save the newly entered passwords, i have got nothing in view, it doesn't move at all. I have tried manually input the specified url in the action of the form, and the page is displayed. I wonder how that can be fixed ? (the submit button of the form need fixing) . Thank you for any help.........

Comment: put the comeplete url with protocol "http://", in action="google.com"

Comment: If you are satisfied by any of the answers check mark it with a upvote in it....this will inspire you to move ahead in Stackoverflow and motivate the answering SO to answer more

Answer (score 1):

put the comeplete url with protocol "http://" along with google.com, in action="google.com"

it is treating as a relative path to a file called google.com

i.e.

```
<form method="POST" action="http://www.google.com/" id="pwdChange">
```

Answer (score 1):

As it is, your form specifies the `action` parameter as `google.com`. This is treated as a relative path to a file called `google.com` on the local webserver. If you want to submit a form to an external domain, you will need to specify a *FULL* url for the `action` parameter - e.g.

```
<form method="POST" action="http://www.google.com/" id="pwdChange">
```

Comment: You mean i can't insert something like `action="../folder/file"`

Comment: @OhDude you can but thats different case if ur file is located outsite the current folder u r presently in and is placed in different folder, here we are pointing you for wrong implmentation of action